# Convert string format to LatLng format using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to draw polyline in a map, totally new to PHP,I tried already researched previous topic but their format doesn't match to the one I need or using other dev language.

How to convert `$polylines_data` as string

`$polylines_data="9.76716,118.74789000000001,9.76665,118.74787,9.766100000000002,118.74787,9.76609,118.74773,9.76609,118.74745000000001,9.76519,118.74742,9.7644,118.74737,9.76382,118.74734000000001,9.7626,118.74728,9.76125,118.7472,9.760670000000001,118.74719,9.760280000000002,118.74724,9.75932,118.74741000000002,9.75826,118.74757000000001,9.75787,118.74763000000002,9.7575,118.74766000000001,9.757290000000001,118.74765000000001,9.756670000000002,118.74752000000001,9.755870000000002,118.74736000000001,9.75567,118.74732000000002,9.755320000000001,118.74732000000002,9.75441,118.74749000000001,9.753960000000001,118.74759000000002,9.753210000000001,118.74776000000001,9.752730000000001,118.74778,9.752510000000001,118.74777,9.75197,118.74773,9.75145,118.74772000000002,9.750720000000001,118.74776000000001,9.75051,118.74777,9.749300000000002,118.74785000000001,9.749270000000001,118.74863,9.74925,118.74941000000001,9.74914,118.75251000000002,9.747770000000001,118.75248,9.74609,118.75245000000001,9.74606,118.75307000000001,9.746080000000001,118.75314000000002,9.746120000000001,118.75316000000001,9.74624,118.75316000000001";`

into **this format or set of orders using PHP**

```
[
[-122.483696, 37.833818],
[-122.483482, 37.833174],
[-122.483396, 37.8327],
[-122.483568, 37.832056],
[-122.48404, 37.831141],
[-122.48404, 37.830497],
[-122.483482, 37.82992],
[-122.483568, 37.829548],
[-122.48507, 37.829446],
[-122.4861, 37.828802],
[-122.486958, 37.82931],
[-122.487001, 37.830802],
[-122.487516, 37.831683],
[-122.488031, 37.832158],
[-122.488889, 37.832971],
[-122.489876, 37.832632],
[-122.490434, 37.832937],
[-122.49125, 37.832429],
[-122.491636, 37.832564],
[-122.492237, 37.833378],
[-122.493782, 37.833683]
]
```

I'm trying to implement it here on client's end, all I need is the format from the backend end using PHP.

```
map.addSource('route', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'properties': {},
'geometry': {
'type': 'LineString',
'coordinates': [
[-122.483696, 37.833818],
[-122.483482, 37.833174],
[-122.483396, 37.8327],
[-122.483568, 37.832056],
[-122.48404, 37.831141],
[-122.48404, 37.830497],
[-122.483482, 37.82992],
[-122.483568, 37.829548],
[-122.48507, 37.829446],
[-122.4861, 37.828802],
[-122.486958, 37.82931],
[-122.487001, 37.830802],
[-122.487516, 37.831683],
[-122.488031, 37.832158],
[-122.488889, 37.832971],
[-122.489876, 37.832632],
[-122.490434, 37.832937],
[-122.49125, 37.832429],
[-122.491636, 37.832564],
[-122.492237, 37.833378],
[-122.493782, 37.833683]
]
}
}
});
```

Really appreciate if you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `-122.483696` in the string ?

Comment: Those are just sample I want to follow. I'm more concerning about the format itself regardless the string item representation.

Comment: Why don't you put exact output you want, not it's not quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and foreach over result to get what you want:

```
<?php

$polylines_data="9.76716,118.74789000000001,9.76665,118.74787,9.766100000000002,118.74787,9.76609,118.74773,9.76609,118.74745000000001,9.76519,118.74742,9.7644,118.74737,9.76382,118.74734000000001,9.7626,118.74728,9.76125,118.7472,9.760670000000001,118.74719,9.760280000000002,118.74724,9.75932,118.74741000000002,9.75826,118.74757000000001,9.75787,118.74763000000002,9.7575,118.74766000000001,9.757290000000001,118.74765000000001,9.756670000000002,118.74752000000001,9.755870000000002,118.74736000000001,9.75567,118.74732000000002,9.755320000000001,118.74732000000002,9.75441,118.74749000000001,9.753960000000001,118.74759000000002,9.753210000000001,118.74776000000001,9.752730000000001,118.74778,9.752510000000001,118.74777,9.75197,118.74773,9.75145,118.74772000000002,9.750720000000001,118.74776000000001,9.75051,118.74777,9.749300000000002,118.74785000000001,9.749270000000001,118.74863,9.74925,118.74941000000001,9.74914,118.75251000000002,9.747770000000001,118.75248,9.74609,118.75245000000001,9.74606,118.75307000000001,9.746080000000001,118.75314000000002,9.746120000000001,118.75316000000001,9.74624,118.75316000000001";


$coords = explode(',', $polylines_data);
$points = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($coords); $i += 2) {
    $points[] = array((float)$coords[$i+1], (float)$coords[$i]);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($points);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74789
            [1] => 9.76716
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74787
            [1] => 9.76665
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74787
            [1] => 9.7661
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74773
            [1] => 9.76609
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74745
            [1] => 9.76609
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74742
            [1] => 9.76519
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74737
            [1] => 9.7644
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74734
            [1] => 9.76382
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74728
            [1] => 9.7626
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.7472
            [1] => 9.76125
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74719
            [1] => 9.76067
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74724
            [1] => 9.76028
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74741
            [1] => 9.75932
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74757
            [1] => 9.75826
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74763
            [1] => 9.75787
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74766
            [1] => 9.7575
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74765
            [1] => 9.75729
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74752
            [1] => 9.75667
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74736
            [1] => 9.75587
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74732
            [1] => 9.75567
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74732
            [1] => 9.75532
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74749
            [1] => 9.75441
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74759
            [1] => 9.75396
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74776
            [1] => 9.75321
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74778
            [1] => 9.75273
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74777
            [1] => 9.75251
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74773
            [1] => 9.75197
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74772
            [1] => 9.75145
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74776
            [1] => 9.75072
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74777
            [1] => 9.75051
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74785
            [1] => 9.7493
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74863
            [1] => 9.74927
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.74941
            [1] => 9.74925
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75251
            [1] => 9.74914
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75248
            [1] => 9.74777
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75245
            [1] => 9.74609
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75307
            [1] => 9.74606
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75314
            [1] => 9.74608
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75316
            [1] => 9.74612
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118.75316
            [1] => 9.74624
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For future search for anyone, you just need to `json_encode($points)` to get the raw format. Thanks a lot @MorganFreeFarm